# How do I change a Master Page to use the SharePoint-Online team site's Master Page?

Tags: sharepoint-online

We migrated a site collection from 2010 to SharePoint Online.  The Parent site Master Page is 'Seattle' We like the Master page used by the SharePoint Online Team Site.  How can I change the parent site to use the same Master Page as the Team Site?
I thought I could get the name of the Team Sites Master Page from site settings.
But its not displayed.  I'm only be able to see Master Page on the Parent site for the site collection.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to copy the Master Page from the Team Site to the top level.  Hope I read your question right, it's 130 AM here.